# How do I reset a Fortigate firewall password without resetting the firewall

Tags: firewall, fortigate

I am new to IT, and I want to login to a Fortigate 60D firewall, but I don't know the password. How do I reset the firewall password without resetting the firewall.

Comment: You ask the network admins to give you an admin account so that you can reset the password. It sounds like you are attempting to break into the firewall for something which you don't want the admins to know about.

Comment: What do you mean by "without resetting"? Do you mean you can't reboot the device? Or you only want to prevent loss of configuration?

Answer (score 6):

Hey you could have just googled that and the first link is your answer. [Here](http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/1708/Resetting_a_lost_admin_password.pdf).

Do some research before asking please.

Here's the steps in short:

1. connect to the fgt with a com cable, if not com port then use USB cable with fortiexplorer. Start the console.
2. reboot the device and wait for it to ask for the username
3. Type in the username: `maintainer`

The password is bcpb+ the serial number of  the firewall (letters of the serial number are in UPPERCASE format)

`Example:bcpbFGT60C3G10016011`

Note:
On some devices, after the device boots, you have only 14 seconds or less to type in the username and password. It might, therefore, be necessary to have the credentials ready in a text editor, and then copy and paste them into the login screen. There is no indicator of when your time runs out so it is possible that it might take more than one attempt to succeed.

4. Once logged reset your admin password using:

`config system admin
edit admin
set password <psswrd>
end`

Comment: seems the maintainer login option doesn't work all the time or sorta disabled in later releases?